# Is there a way to monitor/log all internet requests from Flash/AC3 application?

Tags: linux, flash, actionscript-3, logging

I have a Flash-based (AC3) application which does some network activity. Is there any way to see what requests it generates? Something like network console.

Sources are not available and there is no way to modify the application.

I'm on Linux platform (Ubuntu), so don't have any Flash developer tools. The only solution that comes to my head is to setup traffic logging on OS level.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run Wireshark or Snort. By defining filters (in the case of Wireshark) or rules (in the case of Snort), you can whittle it down.

It will also help if you stop other services/daemons/programs using the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You could run it through a local proxy such as [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is another proxy for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use httpWatch which let's you track all requests just like Fiddler.
You can find it here and download the free version: http://www.httpwatch.com/?gclid=CMr11s6-qKQCFcHr7QodjXRW5w